# BootStrap CSS margin 0 auto not center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using BootStrap 3. Well I can't make the button group center.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">             
 <div class="btn-group" style="margin:0 auto">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >Left</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >Middle</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >Right</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I fixed that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: Guillemo Mansilla's answer is better.  Same technique but better use of existing Bootstrap classes.**

You can set `text-align: center` on the `.container`. No need for the `margin: 0 auto`.

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

**http://jsbin.com/oyaDokOw/2/edit**

Answer (score 19):

Bootstrap 4 use

## Use `text-center` or `mx-auto` or `container-fluid`

1. You could use this hack `text-center` (this does not only apply for text)
2. Or use the exact boostrap4 class `mx-auto`

example 
`class="text-center"` or  `class="mx-auto"`

in context

```html
<div class="btn-group text-center"> or <div class="btn-group mx-auto">
```

**TRY NOT TO USE** inline styles (bad practice)

```html
<div class="btn-group" style="margin:0 auto">
```

---

**References here:**

`text-center` => 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/

`mx-auto` => https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to use inline styles, just apply the class "text-center" which is already included in bootstrap